# Converting NTFS to Ext3

Tags: filesystems, partition, ext3

I recently partitioned a new drive in windows to NTFS.  I want to make it ext3 so that I can transfer a WUBI Ubuntu installation onto it.  I don't care about the data on this partition.

Is there a simple way to do this in either ubuntu or windows 7?

Comment: you can also use a tool i forget the name to mount ntfs drives, but need to mess with ftabs to automount and stuff like that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't convert, but can reformat the partition. Boot into Ubuntu or from a live CD and format the partition from there. Be careful not to format the wrong partition.

```
mkfs.ext3 /dev/hdx1
```

Comment: Is that enough, or will Linux need you to change the partition table partition type too before it'll be happy?

Comment: Linux generally doesn't care if the partition type is right, and it definitely does not if you explicitly specify it in `/etc/fstab` or in your `mount` command.